# python with pymongo and TTL on collections with expireAfterSeconds

Tags: python, mongodb, ttl

Consider the following code

```
mongoconn = pymongo.Connection('localhost', 27017)
mongodb = mongoconn.my_db
posts = mongodb.dataset
posts.create_index("date", expireAfterSeconds=30)
post = { 'date' : datetime.utcnow(), "user" : "testtesttest" , "many" : "yeay"}
a = 0
while a < 5:
        a += 1
        posts.insert(post)
        time.sleep(1)
```

I am posting 5 of these into the database but I see only 1. Is that supposed to happen? Does it have something to do with not setting the _id?

```
> db.dataset.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54c802b8c16e241f3396f4e5"), "date" : ISODate("2015-01-27T21:27:20Z"), "many" : "yeay", "user" : "testtesttest" }
```

Mongodb 2.6.7

Any ideas? I am trying to insert multiple rows and then have mongodb delete them as the TTL expires on the data..

Comment: You are inserting a doc without id, so mongo sets an id on it. In next iteration you insert a doc which already has an id. Now I'm not sure but it should throw an exception? Are you saying it fails silently? Anyway if you move `post = {...}` definition inside the loop it should work.

Comment: The reason it's not raising DuplicateKeyError is that you are using pymongo.Connection, which does unacknowledged write operations by default. Use pymongo.MongoClient instead. Connection is deprecated and removed in PyMongo 3.0.

Comment: Ah yes that explains it. Thanks. I can confirm it works!